# Uninstalling app from iOS Device thru command line

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, command-line, uninstallation

I'm running test on an app using UIAutomation, but I need a way to uninstall the app in a device (iPhone, iPad, iPod) without using jailbreak.

Currently I´m using fruitstrap to upload the app to a cable connected device using the device UID.

Is there a way thru a command line (yes it MUST be command line) to delete the app from the device?

Answer (score 10):

Use the fantastic `mobiledevice` tool!

[mobiledevice repo on GitHub](https://github.com/imkira/mobiledevice)

It compiles in seconds and it let you interact with the connected iOS devices very easily.

Comment: I was looking for this for so long! 

Comment: Works with iOS13.3

Answer (score 8):

Use `ideviceinstaller`

To install app: `ideviceinstaller -i testApp.ipa`

To uninstall app: If you don't know bundle id, first get bundle id
`ideviceinstaller -l` then

`ideviceinstaller -U com.testPackage.testApp`

Answer (score 4):

New Kid on the block - [ios-deploy](https://github.com/ios-control/ios-deploy) 
MobileDevice was a good tool, however not being actively developed. ios-deploy works great.

Here is the command -

```
ios-deploy --id <device_id> --uninstall_only --bundle_id com.app.testapp
```

(ios-deploy is forked from fruitstrap only)

Answer (score 1):

Via command line: `uninstall [-i/--id device_id] -b/--bundle bundle.app`

Removed the specified bundle identifier (eg com.foo.MyApp) from the specified device, or all attached devices if none are specified.

Used [this](https://github.com/jacksonh/fruitstrap) repository
Note: works with SDK 6.1.3 but not with SDK 6.1.4

Answer (score 1):

For those who still get here by google:
You can installe the ruby gem ios_app_installer (which is a "light" version of ios-deploy) and after installing it use the command

```
ios_app_installer -b <bundle id> -u
```

(The device may have to be connected via USB)