# Remove iOS app from command line

Tags: ios, xcode, jenkins, xcodebuild

So we're building this iOS application. We have performance tests that are automatically run by Jenkins. Of course these tests must be run on the device.

Right now we have a lot of trouble with some tests, and I suspect that they don't clean up after themselves, leaving the app's Documents folder in an uncertain state. Obviously I can fix the cleanup, but this will take a huge time.

I'd love to be able to just **delete the app from the device before running the tests**. Is there any way we can do this via `xcodebuild` or any other automatable tool. Could be even applescript or a non-official tool. The only rule is that we may not jailbreak the device.

Comment: Why don't you make the application to clean up all data when installed?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15886373/uninstalling-app-from-ios-device-thru-command-line

Comment: I've seen this, but never could get it working. Any hint?

Answer (score 1):

One multi-platform option is [libimobiledevice](http://www.libimobiledevice.org/) and the [ideviceinstaller](https://github.com/libimobiledevice/ideviceinstaller) utility. It runs on Linux, Mac and Windows and even supports iOS 9.
As noted in the library webpage, it does not depend on jailbreak.

To delete an app do:

```
ideviceinstaller -uninstall com.somecompany.someapp
```